# How can I add Images to JavaScript quiz app

Tags: javascript, html, image

I was trying to add images for a JavaScript quiz app but I tried everything, adding "img src" attribute in different ways but nothing seems to work...please help it's for a project that needs to be done. here is my code...

```js
const quizData = [{
    question: "Which language runs in a web browser?",
    a: "Java",
    b: "C",
    c: "Python",
    d: "javascript",
    correct: "d",

  },
  {
    question: "What does CSS stand for?",
    a: "Central Style Sheets",
    b: "Cascading Style Sheets",
    c: "Cascading Simple Sheets",
    d: "Cars SUVs Sailboats",
    correct: "b",
  },
  {
    question: "What does HTML stand for?",
    a: "Hypertext Markup Language",
    b: "Hypertext Markdown Language",
    c: "Hyperloop Machine Language",
    d: "Helicopters Terminals Motorboats Lamborginis",
    correct: "a",
  },
  {
    question: "What year was JavaScript launched?",
    a: "1996",
    b: "1995",
    c: "1994",
    d: "none of the above",
    correct: "b",
  },
  {
    question: "Is this a test run?",
    a: "yes it is",
    b: "why do you care?",
    c: "stop asking",
    d: "I don't know",
    correct: "d",
  },
  {
    question: "where do you see yourself in  years?",
    a: "In the gutter",
    b: "Forbes magazine",
    c: "Simple guy",
    d: "outside the country",
    correct: "b",
  },


];

const quiz = document.getElementById('quiz')
const answerEls = document.querySelectorAll('.answer')
const questionEl = document.getElementById('question')
const a_text = document.getElementById('a_text')
const b_text = document.getElementById('b_text')
const c_text = document.getElementById('c_text')
const d_text = document.getElementById('d_text')
const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit')


let currentQuiz = 0
let score = 0

loadQuiz()

function loadQuiz() {

  deselectAnswers()

  const currentQuizData = quizData[currentQuiz]

  questionEl.innerText = currentQuizData.question
  a_text.innerText = currentQuizData.a
  b_text.innerText = currentQuizData.b
  c_text.innerText = currentQuizData.c
  d_text.innerText = currentQuizData.d
}

function deselectAnswers() {
  answerEls.forEach(answerEl => answerEl.checked = false)
}

function getSelected() {
  let answer
  answerEls.forEach(answerEl => {
    if (answerEl.checked) {
      answer = answerEl.id
    }
  })
  return answer
}


submitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const answer = getSelected()
  if (answer) {
    if (answer === quizData[currentQuiz].correct) {
      score++
    }

    currentQuiz++

    if (currentQuiz < quizData.length) {
      loadQuiz()
    } else {
      quiz.innerHTML = `
           <h2>You answered ${score}/${quizData.length} questions correctly</h2>
          
          

           <button onclick="location.reload()">Reload</button>
           `
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="quiz-container" id="quiz">
  <div class="quiz-header">
    <h2 id="question">Question Text</h2>
    <ul>
      <li> <input type="radio" name="answer" id="a" class="answer"> <label for="a" id="a_text">Answer</label> </li>
      <li> <input type="radio" name="answer" id="b" class="answer"> <label for="b" id="b_text">Answer</label> </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
```

I want to add different images whenever the questions changes.How can I do that?

Comment: can you add html ([mcve]), also you don't have any `img` tag in the code currently

Comment: I have added the html code...please check

Comment: your code has errors, your html only has 2 elements instead of 4

Comment: It doesn't have errors the code is long I couldn't add the whole thing here that's why

Comment: make a [mcve] to share

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the image to appear with the innerHTML at the end of the quiz. Maybe the URL you're using isn't absolute? I've added an image with an absolute URL and it works:

```js
const quizData = [{
    question: "Which language runs in a web browser?", correct: "d",
    a: "Java", b: "C", c: "Python", d: "javascript",
    img: "https://placekitten.com/200/200"
  },
  {
    question: "What does CSS stand for?", correct: "b",
    a: "Central Style Sheets", b: "Cascading Style Sheets", c: "Cascading Simple Sheets", d: "Cars SUVs Sailboats",
    img: "https://placekitten.com/300/200"
  },
  {
    question: "What does HTML stand for?", correct: "a",
    a: "Hypertext Markup Language", b: "Hypertext Markdown Language", c: "Hyperloop Machine Language", d: "Helicopters Terminals Motorboats Lamborginis",
    img: "https://placekitten.com/200/300"
  },
  {
    question: "What year was JavaScript launched?", correct: "b",
    a: "1996", b: "1995", c: "1994", d: "none of the above",
    img: "https://placekitten.com/400/200"
  },
  {
    question: "Is this a test run?", correct: "d",
    a: "yes it is", b: "why do you care?", c: "stop asking", d: "I don't know",
    img: "https://placekitten.com/200/400"
  },
  {
    question: "where do you see yourself in  years?", correct: "b",
    a: "In the gutter", b: "Forbes magazine", c: "Simple guy", d: "outside the country",
    img: "https://placekitten.com/500/200"
}];

const quiz = document.getElementById('quiz')
const answerEls = document.querySelectorAll('.answer')
const questionEl = document.getElementById('question')
const a_text = document.getElementById('a_text')
const b_text = document.getElementById('b_text')
const c_text = document.getElementById('c_text')
const d_text = document.getElementById('d_text')
const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit')
const questImg = document.querySelector('.question-container > img')

let currentQuiz = 0
let score = 0

loadQuiz()

function loadQuiz() {

  deselectAnswers()

  const currentQuizData = quizData[currentQuiz]
  questionEl.innerText = currentQuizData.question
  a_text.innerText = currentQuizData.a
  b_text.innerText = currentQuizData.b
  c_text.innerText = currentQuizData.c
  d_text.innerText = currentQuizData.d
  questImg.src = currentQuizData.img
}

function deselectAnswers() {
  answerEls.forEach(answerEl => answerEl.checked = false)
}

function getSelected() {
  let answer
  answerEls.forEach(answerEl => {
    if (answerEl.checked) {
      answer = answerEl.id
    }
  })
  return answer
}


submitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {

      const answer = getSelected()
      
      if (answer) {
        if (answer === quizData[currentQuiz].correct) {
          score++
        }
        currentQuiz++;        
        
      if(currentQuiz < quizData.length) {
           loadQuiz()
       } else {
           quiz.innerHTML = `
           <h2>You answered ${score}/${quizData.length} questions correctly</h2>
          <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200">
           <button onclick="location.reload()">Reload</button>
           `
       }
    }
})
```

```css
.question-container{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}
.question-container > img{
  width: 100px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="quiz"></div>
<div class="question-container">
  <div id="question"></div>
  <img />
</div>

<input id="a" type="checkbox" class="answer" />
<label id="a_text"></label>
<br>
<input id="b" type="checkbox" class="answer" />
<label id="b_text"></label>
<br>
<input id="c" type="checkbox" class="answer" />
<label id="c_text"></label>
<br>
<input id="d" type="checkbox" class="answer" />
<label id="d_text"></label>
<br><br>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: But I want to load the images along side each question with the images changing whenever the question changes. How can I do that?

Comment: @Habeshamix see my edit. You want to add the image source as a value in each object, then add it to the image tag each time a question is loaded.

Comment: it didn't work ... but thanks anyways